# cronjob will not start on weekday

Tags: linux, cron

I have to start a cronjob on every Thursday. Here is the script.

It will not start at all.

Manually it does his work but not as a cronjob.

It should start at 17.00 every Thursday:

```
00 17 * * 4 root cd /var/www/domein.nl/admin/scripts && php -f send_newsletter_subscribers.php
```

also tried to do as text: `wed`

```
33 15 * * wed root cd /var/www/domein.nl/admin/scripts && php -f send_newsletter_subscribers.php
```

Have no idea why it doesn't work.
Does anybody have any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: Have you tried giving full paths of everything? `/bin/php -f /var/www.../scripts/send_newsletter_subscribers.php`

Comment: the path are ok. use these in many other cronjobs to. it is only something wrong in the time piece of the command row. everything else works fine.

Comment: Is the path really `domein.nl`?

Answer (score 1):

Is this an individual user's crontab (edited with crontab -e) or a system level crontab file? If the former, then the syntax is wrong, and you need to remove the user specification ("root").

The time and date fields look fine.

Answer (score 0):

Think about setting some important variables in your /etc/initab (specially PATH and SHELL).

My /etc/initab file contains the following:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/root
```